# How to find a particular function used in a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Let's imagine that you have a block of code like below in one of your **plugin** files.

```
<div class="main-content">
  <?php dummy_function();?>
</div>
```

The plugin has a lot of directories and subdirectories each including many `.php` files. How can I understand where `dummy_function();` is defined (in which file). I guess there was a package in Atom editor which had this functionality but I'm not sure and maybe I'm wrong.

I'm new to WordPress and I'm sorry if my question is easy but I couldn' find my answer anywhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search prefix with `function` for e.g. `function dummy_function` in your code editor

Comment: Often, code editors have a "Find in Files" feature, where you can ask to search an entire directory for a string.